# Examples of the application of a matrix with zero as last row / column?

Tags: matrices

I would very much appreciate it if you could provide me with specific examples from real world phenomena (be it from physics, chemistry, language-structure, computing, botanic, whatever) which can be represented as:

1) an nxn matrix with last row zero
2) an nxn matrix with last column zero

The case in 1) is a right ideal of a ring; the one in 2) a left ideal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: An example of the first is a projection matrix from $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ by zeroing the final coordinate.  For example, maps of 3d objects printed on 2d paper.  The final coordinate may even be used to determine the final output, such as in the case of blueprints of a house having each floor at a different x-y location on the map.

Comment: Further examples would be very welcome. Also for the second case. Thanks to all contributors.